# How to update sessionID in cart_list after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express-session

I use express-sessions and passports. I store token data based on the sessionID stored in cookies which will later be retrieved in the mysql database.

> So far I can store shopping cart data using this sessionID as a token
>   that is stored in cookies and will later be retrieved in the database
>   every request made.

but I got a problem when the user logged in using a passport, which is where the user data is also stored in the session and makes the sessionID change when the user successfully logs in.

**So after successfully logging in the shopping cart data disappears because the sessionID is different**

**Did I make mistake?**

to be honest, I was really confused about the use of this express session

I have tried deleting this : `app.use(passport.session());` and still the sessionID is changed

**Server.js**

```
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    genid: function (req) {
        return uuidv4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    name:keys.session.name,
    secret: keys.session.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling:true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge:keys.session.maxAge, // satu hari,
        sameSite:true,
     }

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
    res.header('X-Frame-Options','deny');
    res.header('X-Content-Type-Options','nosniff');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.cookie('hammerstout_t',req.csrfToken());
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    next();
})

app.use(cors({ origin: keys.origin.url,credentials:true}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var ua = UAparser(req.headers['user-agent']);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(ua, null, '  '));
})
app.use('/api/',[CategoryRoutes, ProductRoutes, CartRoutes, AuthRoutes,TrackRoutes]);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server running on port ! ${port}`);
    }

});
```

**passport-setup-js**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import GoogleStrategy from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import keys from './keys';
import db from './conn';

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    let tokenValue={
        providerId:user.providerId,
        token:user.token,
        user_id:user.id
    }
    done(null, tokenValue)
})
passport.deserializeUser((data, done) => {
    let querySelect = `SELECT us.id,us.displayName,us.email,up.providerId,up.token,up.provider from user as us 
                           left join user_provider as up on us.id = up.user_id 
                           where us.id = ? and up.provider = 'google' and up.providerId = ? and up.token = ?`;
    db.query(querySelect,[data.user_id,data.providerId,data.token], (err, ress) => {
        if(ress.length > 0){
            done(null, ress[0])
        }

    })

})

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        //options for the google strategy
        callbackURL: '/api/auth/google/redirect',
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // console.log(profile);
        // TODO : HARUS VALIDASI DULU
        let queryInsert = `INSERT INTO user set ?; INSERT INTO user_provider set user_id = (SELECT u.id from user as u order by id desc limit 1), ?;`;
        let queryFind = `SELECT us.id from user as us 
                         left join user_provider as up on us.id = up.user_id 
                         where up.providerId = ${profile.id}
                         and up.token = '${accessToken}' group by us.id`;
        let querySelect = `SELECT us.id,us.displayName,us.email,up.providerId,up.token,up.provider from user as us 
                           left join user_provider as up on us.id = up.user_id 
                           where us.id = ? and up.provider = ? and up.providerId = ? and up.token = ?`;
        let user = {
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
        }
        if(profile.gender){
            user.gender = profile.gender
        }
        let user_provider={
            provider:profile.provider,
            providerId:profile.id,
            token:accessToken
        }
        db.query(queryFind, (error, result, fields) => {

            if(error) return done(error);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                return done(null, result[0]);
            }else{

                db.query(queryInsert, [user, user_provider], (err, ress, fields) => {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    if (ress) {
                        db.query(querySelect, [ress[0].insertId, profile.provider, profile.id, accessToken],(err,ress)=>{
                            if (err) return done(err);
                            if(ress.length > 0){
                                return done(null, ress[0]);
                            }

                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    })

)
```

**Controller**

```
export const loginGoogleRedirect = (req,res)=>{

    let payload ={
        id:req.user.id,
        displayName:req.user.displayName,
        email:req.user.email,
        providerId:req.user.providerId,
        token:req.user.token,
        provider:req.user.provider
    };
    jwt.sign(
        payload,
        keys.jwt.secretOrPrivateKey,
        {
            expiresIn: keys.jwt.expiresIn
        }, (err, token) => {
            res.redirect(keys.origin.url + "?token=" + token);
        });
}
```